# how to get mongoos data with selective date

Tags: jquery, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have mongoose schema where I save data with date and I want to get date through select date and get data with specific date and time by using ExpressJS and jQuery get method.

How to query a MongoDB to get date and time, my mongoose schema is

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const sensorSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    topic : {type : String ,index : true},
    value : {type :Number ,index : true},
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now ,  index: true}
})

const Sensor = mongoose.model('Sensors' , sensorSchema)

module.exports = Sensor ;
```

I want create router to get selective date and time and get date from MongoDB

```
router.get('/', (req , res )=>{
    SensorModel.find({topic:'soilreading2'} , function(err , data){
      if (err){
        console.log(err)
      } else{
        res.json(data)
      }
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use current date only instead of a user defined date then [timestamps](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps) are easy to implement.

Else you can change the query like below:

> Note: You need to use new Date().getTime() [as stated by tirmey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59552064/8075882) as default for date.

```
SensorModel.find(
    {
        topic:'soilreading2',
        date:{
              $gt:dateGreaterThanThis,
              $lt:dateLessThanThis
              }
    },
    function(err , data)
    {
        if (err)
            {console.log(err)} 
        else
            {res.json(data)}
   }
)
```

Comment: thanks for response i want get from <input type="date" class="form-control border-success" neme="date-input" id="date-input">
      <span class="input-group-btn ml-2">
           <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Get Chart</button>
      </span> by selecting date  like date is between this and that

Comment: You can do that with this by replacing dateGreaterThanThis and dateLessThanThis

Comment: Just replace in your code the sensormodel.find with this. Else share the entire code on git or something so I can suggest the changes.